# Showing that the units of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ are generated by -1 and $\sqrt[3]{2}-1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I’m reading through the book Catalan’s Conjecture by Schoof, and exercise 4.4 asks to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]^{\times}$ is generated by -1 and $\eta=\sqrt[3]{2}$. Precisely, it states:

Consider the ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{C}$ determined by
$$ \sqrt[3]{2} \mapsto (\sqrt[3]{2}, e^{2 \pi i/3} \sqrt[3]{2}).$$
We denote by $x \mapsto (x’, x’’)$. For $x \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, we define its “length” by $\|x\|^2 = |x’|^2+2|x’’|^2$.

(a) Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$ and put $x=a + b\sqrt[3]{2} + c \sqrt[3]{4}$. Show that
$$\|x\|^2 = 3(a^2+b^2 \sqrt[3]{4} +2c^2 \sqrt[3]{2}).$$

(b) Show that $\eta’$ is a real number satisfying $1/4 < \eta’<1$. Let $u$ be an arbitrary unit of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$. Show that for some integer $k$, either the unit $\epsilon=\pm u \eta^k$ or $\epsilon = \pm u^{-1} \eta^k$ satisfies $1/2<\eta’<1$.

(c) Let $\epsilon$ be a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ satisfying $1/2<\epsilon < 1$. Show that $|\epsilon’’|^2<2$ and hence $\|\epsilon\|^2<5$. Use part (a) to show that $\epsilon=\pm 1$.

My question is only on part (c) and getting the bound $|\epsilon’’|^2<2$. Clearly we need both $\epsilon$ to be a unit and $1/2<\epsilon’<1$ to get the bound $|\epsilon’’|^2<2$, but I am not seeing how the fact that $\epsilon$ is a unit helps in this case. I’ve tried various algebraic manipulations using the bound $1/2<\epsilon (=a+b \sqrt[3]{2} +c \sqrt[3]{4})<1$, but I am not seeing how to use the fact that $\epsilon$ is a unit to get a bound on $\epsilon’’ (=a+b \omega \sqrt[3]{2} + c \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{4})$ where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this post?: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789643/what-are-the-units-in-mathbbz-root-3-of-2

Comment: Thanks @BobDobbs, I have looked at it, the approach there is very similar to the approach in the above exercise, but the approach in the exercise here seems to be  more elementary (e.g. no appeal to Dirichlet’s Unit Theorem).